How to ensure the number of IzPack panels is reflected properly on installation
I'm using IzPack to create an installer for a Spring Boot application. It's working fine but for one small aesthetic issue that I can't find an obvious solution for. I have seven installation steps represented by seven  attributes in the IzPack installation file
<panels>
    <panel classname="CheckedHelloPanel" />
    <panel classname="InfoPanel" id="panel.info"/>
    <panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel" />
    <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="panel.input"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel" id="shortcut.panel"/>
    <panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
</panels>


Seven of them. When I build and run the JAR file to install my application, the panels are displayed with a text saying "Step 1 of 7", "Step 6 of 7", etc. This is fine except for the third panel. For some reason it says "Step 2 of 7" even though it's the third step. I don't see any attributes in my intallation XML that specify the numbering of the steps or the panels. What am I doing wrong here?
